# Faster way to restrict access to folder in windows

Tags: windows, permissions

So suppose I am the user Administrator and I want to deny access to the folder c://folder/ for user "user" on Windows 2016 server. What I can do is to right click the folder, go on security tab, edit permissions for the user "user", deny all, and it would restrict access that way. However, this is impractical for large folders and disk drives (100s of GBs or >1TB) because when I do this, it will enumerate all the files and applies the settings to each one. This can sometimes take hours, and to do this to multiple drives and folders takes an exceptionally long time. Is there another way to do this? For example, perhaps with group policy or active directory?

Comment: You can do it with command line but as each file has its meta data/security attributes adjusted, it will still need to propagate accordingly and take some time to complete. See [icacls](https://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html) and consider using a batch script or command line to process accordingly. You are able to set explicit permissions to a specific folder only and to beneath subfolders and files, that may speed up the time as it won't need to traverse and propagate ACL permissions to all beneath files, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The GPO User Folder Permissions can do it:

Refer to this guide: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/assign-file-folder-permissions-via-group-policy-farid-soltani